# In angular routing when page refreshing error "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found " coming

Tags: angularjs

working with angular routing with $routeProvider, $locationProvider . Routing is working fine but when refreshing the page "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" coming. please help

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Routing</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>

        </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "pages/home.html"
    })
.when("/about", {
    templateUrl: "pages/about.html"
})
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

})
```

Thanks

Comment: Set up the server so it returns `index.html` when a request for a valid route is received.

Comment: Server need to catch your Get methods, so as @TheHeadRush said you need to set up server when ever you get GET methods redirect to desired path.

Comment: I am working on visual studio And VS running the project on local server .